# What are all possible returned value in Jenkins plugin "Sonarqube scanner"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, sonarqube-scan

I have a Jenkins pipeline job which build my application, make a Sonar analysis and then is the quality gate passed I deploy in ou Nexus with `mvn deploy`.

The initial setup was to publish only in case of success (taken from the [official doc](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/sonar/)):

```
stage("Quality Gate"){
      timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') {
          def qg = waitForQualityGate()
          if (qg.status != 'OK') {
              error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
          }
      }
    }
```

and now we want to change a bit the logic gate in Jenkins and we would like to publish in case there no error (but e.g Warning is acceptable).

For that I changed the Jenkins satge to:

```
stage("Quality Gate"){
  timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') {
      def qg = waitForQualityGate()
      if (qg.status == 'Error') {
          error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
      }
  }
}

stage('Deploy to Nexus') {
    sh "mvn deploy -DskipTests"
}
```

but now, it does not seems to work properly: my project is always pushed to Nexus even the Quality gate is in Error in SonarQube.

I have a possible workaround by changing the condition:

```
qg.status != 'OK' || qg.status != 'Warning'
```

Anyone knows what is the exact value for the error status (and possibly other values)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation seems incomplete and there is no other way than guessing the correct return value.

For preventing such issue I suggest to test without exact case like this:

```
if ('error'.equalsIgnoreCase(qg.status) ) {
    error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
}
```

When using such condition my script is working fine, then it seems the value returned is in all capital case: 'ERROR'.

Answer (score 0):

It's configurable via Webhooks in SonarQube Administration setup: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Webhooks

So, the method returns whatever you have configured for all Gateway Rules for OK or failure.

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: FrankerZ, it's kind of self-explained statement that it's returns whatever you have configured. But I'll update, thanks